# Vue D3JS create interactive doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, d3.js, charts

I have a project where I need to recreate a certain doughnut chart. This chart consists of blue section that need pop out and change color when being hovered on. I found some documentation online on how to recreate this animation: [documentation](http://bl.ocks.org/erichoco/6694616).

The problem is that I have tried to implement this solution into my Vue component but it keeps on throwing errors when I am hovering in and out of the chart.

When I hover into the chart I am getting the following error: `Cannot read property 'startAngle' of undefined` on the following line: `path.transition().attr("d", d3.arc().innerRadius(radius * 0.7).outerRadius(radius * 1.08));`. I cannot seem to get why this error is occurring because I am not using the `startAngle` function.

When I mouseout of the chart I am also getting the following error `node.getAttribute is not a function` on line `if (!thisPath.classed("clicked")) {`.

This is my first time using D3.JS and I am still trying to figure out a lot about the library. I like how many diverse graphs you can create with

[image]

This is the complete code of my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="p-3 flex flex-col items-center h-full">
    <div class="w-full flex-1 h-full">
      <div ref="chart" class="flex justify-center h-full"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default {
  name: "DoughnutChartItem",
  props: {
    data: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    height: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    width: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    // // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    // var width = 450;
    // var height = 450;
    var margin = 50;

    // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
    var radius = Math.min(this.width, this.height) / 2 - margin;

    // append the svg object to the div called 'chart'
    var svg = d3
      .select(this.$refs["chart"])
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .attr("viewBox", `0 0 ${this.width} ${this.height}`)
      .append("g")
      .attr(
        "transform",
        "translate(" + this.width / 2 + "," + this.height / 2 + ")"
      );

    // // Create dummy data
    // var data = { a: 9, b: 20, c: 30, d: 8, e: 12 };

    // set the color scale
    var color = d3
      .scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(Object.keys(this.data))
      .range(["#206BF3"]);

    // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
    var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d) {
      return d[1];
    });

    var data_ready = pie(Object.entries(this.data));

    // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
    svg
      .selectAll("whatever")
      .data(data_ready)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr(
        "d",
        d3
          .arc()
          .innerRadius(100) // This is the size of the donut hole
          .outerRadius(radius)
      )
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.data[0]);
      })
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .style("opacity", 0.7);

    svg.on("mouseover", () => {
      this.pathAnim(radius, d3.select(this), 1);
    });
    svg.on("mouseout", () => {
      var thisPath = d3.select(this);
      if (!thisPath.classed("clicked")) {
        this.pathAnim(radius, thisPath, 0);
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    pathAnim(radius, path, dir) {
      switch (dir) {
        case 0:
          path
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .ease("bounce")
            .attr(
              "d",
              d3
                .arc()
                .innerRadius(radius * 0.7)
                .outerRadius(radius)
            );
          break;

        case 1:
          console.log(
            path.transition().attr(
              "d",
              d3
                .arc()
                .innerRadius(radius * 0.7)
                .outerRadius(radius * 1.08)
            )
          );
          // path.transition().attr(
          //   "d",
          //   d3
          //     .arc()
          //     .innerRadius(radius * 0.7)
          //     .outerRadius(radius * 1.08)
          // );
          break;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three issues.

First, you are assigning the "mouseover" (and "mouseout") events to the whole `SVG`.  You want to assign it to each individual `path`.

Second, you are having trouble with `this`.

```
svg.on("mouseover", () => {
  this.pathAnim(radius, d3.select(this), 1);
});
```

Here the `this` variable is the VUE component (hence this.pathAnim is callable). But when you do `d3.select(this)`, you are selecting the whole VUE component and not the `path` element you want to animate (see point one).

You can rewrite this as:

```
var paths = svg //<-- hold reference to selection of paths
    .selectAll('whatever')
    .data(data_ready)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr(
      'd',
      d3
       .arc()
       .innerRadius(100)
       .outerRadius(radius)
    )
    .attr('fill', function (d) {
      return color(d.data[0]);
    })
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .style('stroke-width', '2px')
    .style('opacity', 0.7);

    paths.on('mouseover', (d,i,j) => { //<-- operate on paths
        this.pathAnim(radius, d3.select(j[i]), 1); //<-- use alternate way to select path without needing this variable
    });
```

Third, you are again looking at old `d3` code but using a newer `d3` library.  The ease method [now accepts a function](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#easings-d3-ease) as opposed to a string.

```
path
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .ease(d3.easeBounce) //<-- ease function
    .attr(
        'd',
        d3
         .arc()
         .innerRadius(radius * 0.7)
         .outerRadius(radius)
     );
```

Running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="p-3 flex flex-col" id="one">
      <div class="w-full flex-1">
        <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#one',
        data: {
          type: Array,
          required: true,
        },
        mounted() {
          // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
          var width = 450;
          var height = 450;
          var margin = 40;

          // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
          var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;

          // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
          var svg = d3
            .select('#my_dataviz')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .append('g')
            .attr(
              'transform',
              'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')'
            );

          // Create dummy data
          var data = { a: 9, b: 20, c: 30, d: 8, e: 12 };

          // set the color scale
          var color = d3
            .scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(Object.keys(data))
            .range(['#98abc5', '#8a89a6', '#7b6888', '#6b486b', '#a05d56']);

          // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
          var pie = d3.pie().value(function (d) {
            return d[1];
          });

          var data_ready = pie(Object.entries(data));

          // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
          var paths = svg
            .selectAll('whatever')
            .data(data_ready)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr(
              'd',
              d3
                .arc()
                .innerRadius(100) // This is the size of the donut hole
                .outerRadius(radius)
            )
            .attr('fill', function (d) {
              return color(d.data[0]);
            })
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .style('stroke-width', '2px')
            .style('opacity', 0.7);

          paths.on('mouseover', (d,i,j) => {
            this.pathAnim(radius, d3.select(j[i]), 1);
          });
          paths.on('mouseout', (d,i,j) => {
            var thisPath = d3.select(j[i]);
            if (!thisPath.classed('clicked')) {
              this.pathAnim(radius, thisPath, 0);
            }
          });
        },
        methods: {
          pathAnim(radius, path, dir) {
            switch (dir) {
              case 0:
                path
                  .transition()
                  .duration(500)
                  .ease(d3.easeBounce)
                  .attr(
                    'd',
                    d3
                      .arc()
                      .innerRadius(radius * 0.7)
                      .outerRadius(radius)
                  );
                break;

              case 1:
                //console.log(
                  path
                  .transition()
                  .attr(
                    'd',
                    d3
                      .arc()
                      .innerRadius(radius * 0.7)
                      .outerRadius(radius * 1.08)
                  )
                //);
                // path.transition().attr(
                //   "d",
                //   d3
                //     .arc()
                //     .innerRadius(radius * 0.7)
                //     .outerRadius(radius * 1.08)
                // );
                break;
            }
          },
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Update for Comments (d3.js V6.0)**

Sorry, I missed that one.  The event handling [changed significantly](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide) in version 6.  See updates below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="p-3 flex flex-col" id="one">
      <div class="w-full flex-1">
        <div id="my_dataviz"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      new Vue({
        el: '#one',
        data: {
          type: Array,
          required: true,
        },
        mounted() {
          // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
          var width = 450;
          var height = 450;
          var margin = 40;

          // The radius of the pieplot is half the width or half the height (smallest one). I subtract a bit of margin.
          var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;

          // append the svg object to the div called 'my_dataviz'
          var svg = d3
            .select('#my_dataviz')
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .append('g')
            .attr(
              'transform',
              'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')'
            );

          // Create dummy data
          var data = { a: 9, b: 20, c: 30, d: 8, e: 12 };

          // set the color scale
          var color = d3
            .scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(Object.keys(data))
            .range(['#98abc5', '#8a89a6', '#7b6888', '#6b486b', '#a05d56']);

          // Compute the position of each group on the pie:
          var pie = d3.pie().value(function (d) {
            return d[1];
          });

          var data_ready = pie(Object.entries(data));

          // Build the pie chart: Basically, each part of the pie is a path that we build using the arc function.
          var paths = svg
            .selectAll('whatever')
            .data(data_ready)
            .enter()
            .append('path')
            .attr(
              'd',
              d3
                .arc()
                .innerRadius(100) // This is the size of the donut hole
                .outerRadius(radius)
            )
            .attr('fill', function (d) {
              return color(d.data[0]);
            })
            .attr('stroke', 'black')
            .style('stroke-width', '2px')
            .style('opacity', 0.7);

          paths.on('mouseover', (e,d) => {
            this.pathAnim(radius, d3.select(e.currentTarget), 1);
          });
          paths.on('mouseout', (e,d) => {
            var thisPath = d3.select(e.currentTarget);
            if (!thisPath.classed('clicked')) {
              this.pathAnim(radius, thisPath, 0);
            }
          });
        },
        methods: {
          pathAnim(radius, path, dir) {
            switch (dir) {
              case 0:
                path
                  .transition()
                  .duration(500)
                  .ease(d3.easeBounce)
                  .attr(
                    'd',
                    d3
                      .arc()
                      .innerRadius(radius * 0.7)
                      .outerRadius(radius)
                  );
                break;

              case 1:
                //console.log(
                  path
                  .transition()
                  .attr(
                    'd',
                    d3
                      .arc()
                      .innerRadius(radius * 0.7)
                      .outerRadius(radius * 1.08)
                  )
                //);
                // path.transition().attr(
                //   "d",
                //   d3
                //     .arc()
                //     .innerRadius(radius * 0.7)
                //     .outerRadius(radius * 1.08)
                // );
                break;
            }
          },
        },
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the `j` in the `(d,i,j)` ?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. I have tried the snippet but it doesn't work with my V6(Which I am using at the moment) I can downgrade to V5 but is there a way to make this work for V6? I am getting the following error: `Cannot read property '#<Object>' of undefined` when I update to `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>`

Comment: @dgknca, in d3.js < 6 `j` was the selection (collection of elements) in the current data-binding.  This changed significantly in version 6, see above.

Comment: @Mark Thank you very much. You are an angel!! Keep up the good work :).

Comment: @Mark thanks for detailed explanation mate!